# How to get the img_url to display from Firebase Storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am looking for a way to get an image path from firebase storage in React.js.
I tried to implement the code below.
but the URL of ＜img src = {{imgUrl}} /＞ is [object%20Object].
How Can I fix and improve my code?

```
const Apple = (props) => {

  const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState("");
  let img_urla="";

  const getImage = () =>{
    let ref = storage.ref().child('/images/thumbs/super_potato.jpeg');
    ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      setImgUrl(url);
      img_urla = url;
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getImage();
  });

  const { board , state } = props;
  if (board) {
    return (
      <div className="container section project-details">
            <p>{board.content}</p>
            <img src = {{imgUrl}} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your line can simply be `<img src={imgUrl} />`. If you do `{{imgUrl}}`, what it does is create an object which is why you are getting the error.